# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Tags: javascript, jquery

The javascript works on the page, however I can't compile this with the uglifier gem because there is an error - I can't find it though..

tracks.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();

    $('.show_hide').click(function () {
        $(this).(".slidingDiv").slideToggle(); // line console is complaining about
    });  
});
```

I have one div, when clicked slides another div down.

Comment: "The javascript works on the page"... that bit doesn't. It contains a syntax error after `$(this)`. Look at the console [in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/Namzd/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shouldn't this

```
$(this).(".slidingDiv").slideToggle(); //Syntax error here?
```

be

```
$(this).find(".slidingDiv").slideToggle(); //provided your slidingDiv is inside '.show_hide'
```

Comment: quick answer thanks! you were right on the money